# MVC5 with EF6 Repository Pattern implementation for Functions and Procedures

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I'am implementing repository pattern in my large ASP.NET MVC5 application .Every think is fine with tables and views but I'm a little bit confuse how to make repository for functions and procedures that are imported like methods.

```
_context.spGetSomething(1,"name");
```

The all repository for functions and procedures that I found were using sql command or sql query. Is there any example of good practice with imported procedures ?

My Repository look like this now

```
interface IRepository<T>:IDisposable
{
 void Delete(int ID);
 void Update(T entity)
 void Insert(T entity)
 IQueryable Select()
}



public abstract class AbstractRepository<T>:IRepositori<T>
{
         protected MyDbContext context;
         public AbstractRepository(MyDbContext db)
         {
         context= db;
         }

  //interface implementation
}
```

And in controller

```
public MyController:Controller
{
 private IRepository<MyModel> _repository;
 MyController()
{
 _repository= new MyRepository(dbcontext);
}
// some actions 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

We use a special/extra InfoEntity and InfoRepository for stored procedures and this convension works great. Our BaseRepository has 2 methods: SelectInfo and ListInfo.

But we are using Dapper as ORM and I don't have expirence with EntityFramework.

Something else: you can use an IoC container like Unity to insert via constructor of your controller the Repository instance. Delivers beter separation beween Data access layer and is beter testable.